# Filezilla shared settings problem fzdefaults.xml

Tags: filezilla

I am trying to configure FileZilla so that I can use the same settings, etc on all of my networked machines, so to start, I am creating a fxdefaults.xml file, [per this article](http://jonathanstegall.com/2008/05/26/sharing-a-filezilla-profile/).  Ultimately, I want the settings to reside on a network drive, but to get this up and running, I have simply put the settings on a local drive on my Windows 7 box, d:\filezilla. Everything looks straight-forward, and I have defined the fzdefaults.xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<FileZilla3>
  <Settings>
    <Setting name="Config Location">d:\filezilla</Setting>
    <Setting name="Kiosk mode">1</Setting>
    <Setting name="Disable update check">1</Setting>
  </Settings>
</FileZilla3>
```

I have created the directory d:\filezilla, and have copied all of my filezilla user settings into this directory, ensuring they aren't read-only, and the SYSTEM account has full control of the files.

However, when I start filezilla, I get numerous error messages such as "Failed to write XML file", and finally a summary of errors:

```
3:55:42 PM: Directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla FTP Client\$SOMEDIR\filezilla' couldn't be created (error 3: the system cannot find the path specified.)
3:55:42 PM: can't open file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla FTP Client\$SOMEDIR\filezilla\filezilla.xml' (error 3: the system cannot find the path specified.)
3:55:45 PM: can't open file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla FTP Client\$SOMEDIR\filezilla\layout.xml' (error 3: the system cannot find the path specified.)
3:55:47 PM: can't open file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla FTP Client\$SOMEDIR\filezilla\filters.xml' (error 3: the system cannot find the path specified.)
3:55:47 PM: can't open file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla FTP Client\$SOMEDIR\filezilla\filters.xml' (error 3: the system cannot find the path specified.)
3:55:49 PM: can't open file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla FTP Client\$SOMEDIR\filezilla\bookmarks.xml' (error 3: the system cannot find the path specified.)
3:56:26 PM: can't open file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla FTP Client\$SOMEDIR\filezilla\bookmarks.xml' (error 3: the system cannot find the path specified.)
```

Looking at those, it looks like it isn't looking in the correct location for the config files, yet I am specifying the location as d:\filezilla and it exists... any ideas?

Removing the fzdefaults.xml file from the app directory clears the errors, but leaves the config files in their default location.

Comment: Do you have permission to write back to that location via Filezilla?

Comment: I would assume so... wouldn't FileZilla use the SYSTEM account? My personal account that I am logged in with does as well.

Answer (score 0):

FZ uses the fzdefaults.xml file located in the program folder. Did you copy your version of the file to that location?

And you could try a trailing backslash
    d:\filezilla\